# Vue chartjs bar chart sometimes only shows x-axis and y-axis, the bar and labels are missing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I tried to find out why sometimes the component does not function well, but I still do not find why, the console has no information (no errors, no warnings..), I use the below script for bar chart components:

```js
    // Chart.js
    import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

    export default {
        extends: Bar,
        props: ['data', 'labels'],
        mounted() {
            // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
            this.renderBarChart();
        },
        computed: {
            chartData: function () {
                return this.data;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            renderBarChart() {
                var cdata = {
                    labels: this.labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: '',
                            backgroundColor: globalSetting.backgroundColors, //global.js loading before 
                            borderColor: globalSetting.borderColor,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            data: this.chartData
                        }
                    ]
                }
                let options = {
                     legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Levels'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Numbers'
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
                this.renderChart(cdata, options);
            }
        },
        watch: {
            data: function () {
                this.renderBarChart();
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }
```

And in my html,

```html
<div v-if="!loading">
<p>{{c.chartData}} {{labels}}</p>
 <bar :data="c.chartData" :labels="labels"></bar>
</div>
```

**Sometimes**, the chart is plotted without bar and labels information (as the below image) but `<p>{{c.chartData}}{{labels}}</p>` have values. After refresh the page, everything is correct. Any idea? Thank you
[image]

Comment: check in console if there is any error on initial render

Comment: There is no error message in console.

Comment: When labels loading is super slow, it will display incorrectly. In the above code, `!loading` is only checking `c.chartdata`, so I added another 'v-if' to chart to check label loading. I guess it is the reason. I will see whether the error happens again or not